# Convert single MariaDB to a Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I have the next question that I don't know how to solve.

I currently have a server running mariadb version 10.1 on a Debian 9.8. This server is for test environments so it is not a real production environment.

Now I need to create a cluster using a gallery to have two nodes. I already have the second server mounted, but I don't know what are the steps to configure the Galera cluster of a node with databases already created and with information and with another node completely from scratch. What would be the steps and what should be done?

Comment: The minimum are 3 Nodes to create a Galera Cluster.

Comment: Here is the Doku https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-started-with-mariadb-galera-cluster/

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. But this documentation does not solve anything. I have already been able to configure a galley cluster from scratch. But now the situation that is proposed to me is having a mysql database server in standalone mode, with databases created and with information already within those databases, I don't know what is the procedure to form a galley cluster and that all the server information that is already configured to the cluster is replicated.

Comment: I suggest you consider upgrading to 10.3 _first_, since it will be easier to do it on a single node than a complete cluster.

Comment: s/galley/Galera/  and  s/gallery/Galera/

Comment: You need to _configure_ the second node, but not load the data.  The bootstrap will take care of copying (via "SST") the data from your first node to the second.